# enable or disable eclipse menu - org.eclipse.ui.actionSets, based on value in preference

Tags: eclipse-plugin

I have an eclipse plugin, where i have created the menus using actionSets.

```
<extension point="org.eclipse.ui.actionSets">
    <actionSet description="My Sample"
   id="MySample.actionSet"
  label="My Sample"
 visible="true">
<menu
 id="mysample.actionset.menu1"
 label="My Sample">
 <groupMarker
   name="mysample.groupCreatesimilar">
 </groupMarker>
</menu>
<action
  class="org.mysample.actions.create.MyCreateCodeAction"
  definitionId="MySample.myCreateCode.command"
  id="MySample.myCreateCode.command"
  label="Create Sample Code"
  menubarPath="mysample.actionset.menu1/mysample.groupMarker2">
</action>
</actionSet>
</extension>
```

I need to enable or disable one of these menu based on a value in preference. I am able to achieve this when i use command as below. But i m not supposed to do it this way. I have to get it working with the code above (actionSet). Please suggest how this can be done.

```
<extension
     point="org.eclipse.ui.menus">
  <menuContribution
        locationURI="menu:org.eclipse.ui.main.menu?after=additions">
     <menu
           label="my label"
           id="myMenu.menu1">
        <command
              commandId="MySample.myCreateCode.command"
              mnemonic="S"
              id="MySample.myCreateCode.command">
        </command>
     </menu>
  </menuContribution>

    </extension>
```

Comment: `actionSets` are now deprecated with `org.eclipse.ui.menus` being the recommended way to do menus.

Comment: My application is legacy one, so i cannot change to use org.eclipse.ui.menus. In such a case, can i not do the enabling/disabling?

Answer (score 0):

The entire `actionSet` should appear in the `Window / Customize Perspective` dialog `Command Groups Availability` tab where it can be turned on / off.

To enable / disable an individual action you probably need to call `Action.setEnabled()` in the action code - something like:

```
public class MyCodeCreateAction extends Action
{
  MyCodeCreateAction()
  {
    super();

    IPreferenceStore prefs = Activator.getDefault().getPreferenceStore();

    setEnabled(prefs.getBoolean("preference"));

    prefs.addPropertyChangeListener(new PropertyChangeListener());
  }


  private class PropertyChangeListener implements IPropertyChangeListener
  {
    @Override
    public void propertyChange(final PropertyChangeEvent event)
    {
      if ("preference".equals(event.getProperty()))
       {
         final IPreferenceStore prefs = Activator.getDefault().getPreferenceStore();

         setEnabled(prefs.getBoolean("preference"));
       }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate little more